# Libreoffice Calc Is it possible to edit the data description of a diagram legend

Tags: excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

[image: Here is the legend of a diagram in Excel]

**I would like to have the same legend in Libre office Calc, but I don't know how I could edit a diagram legend in Libre**
[image: This is the diagram legend in Libre]

**This is the diagram in Libre, does anyone know how to edit it so

Answer (score 1):

Select the chart by double-clicking. Click Data Ranges. Go to the Data Series tab. Select the series one at a time and enter their name in the Range For Name field (in double quotes).

[image: EditLegend.png]

You can create all the necessary labels in the cells of the sheet and indicate in this field the addresses of the required cells.

Comment: Well I think for me it is a little bit more complex than that in your answer - I uploaded a .ods file in my post, could you have a look at it please? @JohnSUN

Comment: OneDrive? Forgive me, this resource is not available to me (and I do not consider it necessary to create an MS account for the sake of downloading one file).

Comment: is there any other way I could share it to you?

Comment: Reask on ask.libreoffice.org (there you can attach your file directly to the question) or use DropBox or GoogleDrive

Comment: https://www.libreoffice-forum.de/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=35860

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you did when you attached the file there. Go to that thread and just look at the size of the attached file - only 6 bytes. This is anything but a spreadsheet.